# How can I find my jssc library manually in Arduino

Tags: java, arduino

When I am trying to use the Serial Plotter or Serial Monitor in Arduino 1.8.8, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\Zafer Do?ukan Cincil.jssc\windows\jSSC-2.8_x86.dll: Can't
>   find dependent libraries  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)     at
>   java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)   at
>   jssc.SerialNativeInterface.(SerialNativeInterface.java:172)
>     at jssc.SerialPort.(SerialPort.java:120)  at
>   processing.app.Serial.(Serial.java:135)     at
>   processing.app.Serial.(Serial.java:82)  at
>   processing.app.SerialMonitor$4.(SerialMonitor.java:101)     at
>   processing.app.SerialMonitor.open(SerialMonitor.java:101)     at
>   processing.app.Editor.handleSerial(Editor.java:2222)  at
>   processing.app.Editor.lambda$buildToolsMenu$17(Editor.java:719)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:842)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:886)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I am able to upload my sketch to my Arduino and run it properly without problems. However, whenever I try to open the Plotter/Monitor, this error comes up, starting with:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\Zafer Do?ukan Cincil.jssc\windows\jSSC-2.8_x86.dll: Can't
>   find dependent libraries

I looked up to that particular path, and I can find the jSSC-2.8_x86.dll file there. What could be the reason for the error? I have a letter 'ğ' in my user name (hence in my path), which is shown as '?' in the error note. Could that be the problem? If yes, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better responses

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was because of my user name containing a character that could not be noticed by arduino. I created a new user and I am programming over that profile.